# echarts world map from baidu. show popover on clicking a location

Tags: popover, echarts

I am using echarts world map for showing location relations in my project. My requirement is that I want to show a popover just like a tooltip when i click a location. How is this possible. please help

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can achieve that popover you wanted just by `tooltip`.
`tooltip.triggerOn` controls the condition of tooltip, its default value is `mousemove` that tooltip would show when your mouse move on a location. You can set the value of `tooltip.triggerOn` to `click` if you want to show a tooltip when you click a location.